# How to save inherited objects in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have three classes

> Rule
>   Contract
>   Trip
>   and class Contract extends Rule.and class Trip has contract object . 
>   TripInstance.contract = contractObj
>   TripInstance.save()

i am not able to save the contract in to table trip.

Comment: Please show the error you get and the complete class source code.

Comment: there is no error message and clientTripInstance.save(flush: true) returns null

Comment: iam getting error : grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():

Comment: Well there you go. You have a validation error on your object. do a println clientTripInstance.errors after save

Comment: if you change `save()` to `save(failOnError: true)` it will throw an exception that shows the cause of the failure. You can set this as the default behavior in `Config.groovy`

Answer (score 2):

By default, Grails sets all properties on domain objects to `nullable: false`.  Since it seems like you're getting a validation error, you might want to make sure that you've added all of the appropriate properties to the instance before you save it.